# Angular JWT Profile user(getting field of json)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, jwt, passport.js

I have a `gettProfile()` method which includes below code:

```
gettProfile(){
    var headers = new Headers();
    this.loadToken();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');  
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});  
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/profile', options)
      .map(res => res.json()); //res.json() localStorage.getItem('students')
  }
```

In this code, when I write `console.log(this.authToken);` It shows right JWT Token. But when I pass this data to my `ProfileComponent` it says:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Profile.component.ts code is below:

```
  export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {  
        students: Object;
          constructor(private authService:AuthService,  private router:Router) { }

          ngOnInit() {  
            this.authService.gettProfile().subscribe(profile => 
            {   
              this.students= profile.students;
            },
            err => {
              console.log(err);
              return false;    
            });
          }
}
```

Profile.component.html code:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h1>Hi {{students.name}}!</h1>
    <p>You're logged in!!</p>
    <h3>Registered user detail:</h3>
    <ul>
        <li *ngIf="students">
            {{students.email}} ({{students.surname}} {{students.address}})
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p><a [routerLink]="['/login']">Logout</a></p>
</div>
```

When I look into LocalStorage:

```
students:
{"id":"5960fa785017042b9c54f05c","name":"aaa","surname":"aaa","email":"aaa@gmail.com","address":"aaaa","phoneNumber":"aaaa"}
token: JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.UEtThW_30lmPeIUCa8sIZtCfjtb4ek6qWxXyKpnWveI
```

My register and authentication work well. But Profile does not work.

How can I handle with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When angular first tries to access `students` it get's undefined as the `getProfile` method is asynchronous. So you should declare an empty `Object` as below:

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {  
    students: Object = {};
    // rest of the code as it is
```

Comment: I tried as you said but it did not work. For example, when I write <li *ngIf="students"> before {{students.name}} the page is white. There is no data. It does not understand as students object. What is this reason?

Comment: can u pls console.log(this.students); below `this.students= profile.students;`, and post it here

Comment: It says undefined.

Comment: that means `profile.students` is undefined. now can u pls `console.log(profile)` and see what ur http request returns ?

Comment: It returns Object {}

Comment: that means `http://localhost:3000/api/profile` is returning empty object, can u pls check ur API with tools like [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en)

Comment: You are right. It is similar with Object {}. This is my  router.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), function(req, res) {
    res.json({students: req.students});    
}); I think it is right :(

Comment: In one of your middleware functions is there a line like `req.students = someVariable`, because `req.students` seems to be empty

Comment: Hmm I understood. I looked 1 day for this but could not figure it out. register and authenticate work well. Could you look my Server.js, api.js and passport.js. I am editing my post with these files.

Comment: @HadiCanim sure

Comment: If you want, I can send my project via email. It uses cloud Mongo DB. You can start the server via node server and angular as ng serve. Or did you figure it out ? I can not access students object in api.js while /profile. What is this main reason?

Comment: I have solved my problem. Thank you very much for your answers. I am getting your answer as accepted answer. The problem was in api.js :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths). Like so:

```
{{students?.name}}
```